# Flash file .exe and .swf system requirement

Tags: flash, exe, cd, system-requirements

I am a new user of adobe flash. I have a question:

After I published my flash file to .exe and .swf, how to I check the system requirement for this project when they need to open it??

I need to write on the cd face....

Answer (score 0):

System requirement would be the dependent on the SWF file version you have set if you created a .swf file. For example, if the SWF version is 13, then you need the latest and greatest Flash player and thus the lowest system requirement would be determined by the flash player's system requirement.

The trick with system requirements is the lowest common denominator. Whichever component in the overall system has the most stringent requirements would determine the requirement for whole system.

With .exe, you are keeping a player inside. Which version of player would determine the requirements.

Answer (score 0):

They will just need the latest version of Adobe AIR (http://get.adobe.com/air/) to be installed on their system